# Htaccess 310 redirection with get paramaters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo

I have a problem with an 301 redirection with get parameters.

My old website had URL like this : 
http://www.mywebsite.com/contacts/?lang=fr

I upload my new website today. And for the seo i would like to redirect this address to the new : http://www.mywebsite.com/contact

I use this redirection in my htaccess but it doesn't work ....

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=fr$
RewriteRule ^contacts$ http://www.mywebsite.com/contact [L,R=301]
```

What's wrong ?
Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: **310** redirect?

Comment: Does `http://www.mywebsite.com/contact` work directly from a browser?

Answer (score 2):

Use below rule,

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=fr$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^contacts$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mywebsite.com/contact [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^contacts/?(.*)$ /contact [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=fr$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^contacts$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mywebsite.com/contact? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works !
But ...
I would like to te the same redirection with another pages : 
http://www.mywebsite.com/photos/?lang=fr
redirect to http://www.mywebsite.com/gallery

How to to make it works ?
Thanks

Comment: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=fr$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^photos$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mywebsite.com/gallery? [L,R=301]`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, it works !
But ...
At the same time I would like to te the same redirection with another pages : 
http://www.mywebsite.com/photos/?lang=fr
redirect to http://www.mywebsite.com/gallery

How to to make it works ?
Thanks